# How do I Receive Messages Using Sinch Javascript Instant Messaging SDK?

Tags: javascript, client, sinch

While trying to build a web application using the Sinch Instant Messaging SDK I ran into an issue of not being able receive instant messages using the latest Javascript Instant Messaging SDK found [here](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/). I have also been following along [this](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/build-instant-messaging-app-sinch-javascript/) tutorial to help build my app that I think uses a different version of the SDK where instant messages can be received. However, the SDK version in the tutorial does not let me use generated userTickets for authentication for my application, while the latest SDK version does.

So, I was wondering if there was a way to either use generated userTickets for the SDK found in the tutorial or receive instant messages using the latest SDK.

On the latest SDK I have tried setting supportActiveConnection to true during configuration in order to receive messages using the code in the tutorial with no success.  Here are some of the relevant code snippets from the tutorial to receive messages:

```
sinchClient = new SinchClient({
    applicationKey: 'APP_KEY',
    capabilities: {
        messaging: true
    },
    supportActiveConnection: true,
});

var loginObject = {
    username: username,
    password: password
};
sinchClient.start(loginObject, function() {
    global_username = username;
    showPickRecipient();
}).fail(handleError);

var messageClient = sinchClient.getMessageClient();

var eventListener = {
    onIncomingMessage: function(message) {
        if (message.senderId == global_username) {
            $('div#chatArea').append('<div>' + message.textBody + '</div>');
        } else {
            $('div#chatArea').append('<div style="color:red;">' + message.textBody + '</div>');
        }
    }
}

messageClient.addEventListener(eventListener);
```

The authentication ticket is generated by a python back-end through the following function and handler:

```
def getAuthTicket(username):
    userTicket = {
        'identity': {'type': 'username', 'endpoint': username},
        'expiresIn': 3600,
        'applicationKey': APPLICATION_KEY,
        'created': datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
    }

    userTicketJson = json.dumps(userTicket).replace(" ", "")
    userTicketBase64 = base64.b64encode(userTicketJson)

    # TicketSignature = Base64 ( HMAC-SHA256 ( ApplicationSecret, UTF8 ( UserTicketJson ) ) )
    digest = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(
        APPLICATION_SECRET), msg=userTicketJson, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    signature = base64.b64encode(digest)

    # UserTicket = TicketData + ":" + TicketSignature
    signedUserTicket = userTicketBase64 + ':' + signature

    return {"userTicket": signedUserTicket}

class TicketHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.write(getAuthTicket(self.username))
```

Then on the client side I call a get request on the ticket handler.

```
$.get('/ticket', function(authTicket) {
    sinchClient.start(eval("(" + authTicket + ")"))
        .then(function() {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
            console.log("fail");
        });
});
```

The error I get when I try to start the start the Sinch client using the sinch.min.js file found in the tutorial is a "no valid identity or authentication ticket".

Comment: You sure can, What error messages are you getting. The code above doesnt use a ticket, its more helpful if I can see the code that doesnt work.

Comment: @cjensen The ticket authentication method I use doesn't work for the sinch.min.js used in the tutorial, but seems to work on the latest version. However, I'm unable to receive messages using the above code for the event listener on the latest version, but can for the version in the tutorial.  I don't get any errors for the latter issue, but I'm unable to receive messages.

Comment: @cjensen I am also experiencing this error, despite using the latest version 1.4.11